# Sonarqube React Stateless functional components should not use 'this'

Tags: reactjs, sonarqube

I have the following react code:

```
class OrdersTable extends PureComponent {
  ...
  table = null;
  ...
  autoSizerRender = ({ columns, sortBy, rowCount, selectAllCheckbox, data, orders }) => {
    return ({ height, width }) => {
      ...

      return (
        <Table
          ref={(table) => (this.table = table)}
          ...
        >
          {this.columnRenderer({ columns, width, selectAllCheckbox })}
        </Table>
      );
    };
  };
  ...
}
```

and then in Sonarqube I get a bug with the following problem : Stateless functional components should not use 'this'. But table is  class component.

Any ideas why and how to fix it?

Sonarqube Developer Edition Version 10.3 / React version 16.13.1